# Java Reading and Splitting file that exceeds memory into slices

Tags: java, split

I have code that reads a file and splits it into pieces. This code works great (I actually used a prior post from this awesome site to make the code, thanks everyone!) but I want to change this code to do two new things.

- First: I want the code to check if the file that's about to be split exceeds memory. **In this case my memory limit is 2 Gigabytes**
- Second: If the file does exceed memory I want to split the file into smaller slices
  and read and flush each slice in sequence until the entire file has been read and flushed to a new split file.

Here's the code that works successfully, it takes a .txt file and splits it into 10 equal parts.

```
package tyler_test;
import java.io.*;

public class testFileSplit 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("File", "r");
    long numSplits = 10; //how many file splits we want
    long sourceSize = raf.length();
    long bytesPerSplit = sourceSize/numSplits ;
    long remainingBytes = sourceSize % numSplits;

    int maxReadBufferSize = 8 * 1024; //8KB
    for(int i=1; i <= numSplits; i++) 
    {
        BufferedOutputStream bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("split."+i));

        if(bytesPerSplit > maxReadBufferSize) 
        {
            long numReads = bytesPerSplit/maxReadBufferSize;
            long numRemainingRead = bytesPerSplit % maxReadBufferSize;
            for(int j=0; j<numReads; j++) 
            {
                readWrite(raf, bw, maxReadBufferSize);
            }

            if(numRemainingRead > 0) 
            {
                readWrite(raf, bw, numRemainingRead);
            }
        }

        else 
        {
            readWrite(raf, bw, bytesPerSplit);
        }
        bw.close();
    }

    if(remainingBytes > 0) 
    {
        BufferedOutputStream bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("split."+(numSplits+1)));
        readWrite(raf, bw, remainingBytes);
        bw.close();
    }
        raf.close();
}

static void readWrite(RandomAccessFile raf, BufferedOutputStream bw, long numBytes) throws IOException 
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[(int) numBytes];
    int val = raf.read(buf);
    if(val != -1) 
    {
        bw.write(buf);
    }
}
```

}

How can I modify this code to meet my new criteria? I want to thank everyone for taking the time to read my question and offer help, I very much appreciate it! And if my question isn't clear enough please let me know and I'll revise it.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: So, you want to split a file into 10 parts, is that right? Whatever the length of the file is, that should take more than a few KB of memory. Just read the file by chunks of, for example, 16KB, and immediately write those 16KB to the destination. When you've reached the size limit of the first destination file, change the destination. You don't need a RAF to do that, and you should never assume that when asking to read N bytes, you will get the N bytes at once.

Comment: I of course meant: that should **not** take more than a few KB of memory.

Answer (score 0):

**[A Suggestion]**
just make use of the good Java Memory mapped Files (MappedByteBuffer).

With a Memory mapped file, you can pretend that the entire file is in memory and that you can access it by simply treating it as a very large array.

```
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("data.txt", "rw");
    FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();

    //A MemoryMappedBuffer has a fixed max-size, but the file it’s mapped to is elastic
    MappedByteBuffer in = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, startPosition, length);
```

you can control the alocated memory by setting the mapped bufferSize. Example, try to read/map i.e "512 MB" per Buffer and repeat this as long as needed(fileSize).

Comment: So with the MappedByteBuffer I can choose how large of a slice of a file is read until the entire file is finally read? Thank you so much for the reply, I'll try that!

Comment: you can read a very large file(>3GB) with one MappedByteBuffer or with many buffers if you want. with channel.map(...., buffersize) you load so much bytes to memory, and so on untill you read the last bytes from the file.